# Connect analysis services to oracle database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, windows-10, tnsnames

I am looking to connect analysis services to an oracle database, and when I hit `Process` in AS, it gives me a generic `Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Oracle: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.`

Things I've tried:

- When I create the tables in VS2017, the connection works
- When I do a tnsping from the command line, that works
- I replaced all of the default tnsnames.ora files in ./app with the one that I know works (its what the TNS_ADMIN env variable is set to

I don't see where the location of the actual utilities used by the service are detailed, so I can't test it using those.

How can I make SSAS use the tnsnames.ora file that I need?

Answer (score 1):

> > How can I make SSAS use the tnsnames.ora file that I need?

The best answer is don't bother.  Use the [Easy Connect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/naming.htm#i498306) naming method, and bypass the TNSNAMES.ORA file entirely.

Alternatively you can set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the folder containing your TSNNAMES.ORA file and *reboot your server* for the SSAS service to see get the changed environment.

Comment: This does look easier. I have special characters in my password (and no ability to change the password to the account). Is there a way to escape them? For what it's worth, I did reboot the server and still no dice.